# how to pass scope in api while generating token for azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-authentication

I'm able to generate access token using postman. But, I need to generate the token from API. I tried to get the token using api referring microsoft document on how to generate access token. But getting the below error while running the post request for oauth2.0

Error --

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope api://f653b343-fe0a-422d-b4a8-f36346a3156b/Access.As.User is not valid.\r\nTrace ID: ce5c37f6-57c0-44f6-b265-ccc68602ba00\r\nCorrelation ID: a44a64c1-9277-40e3-b855-ee0abbe44ab6\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-11 11:54:49Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70011
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-11-11 11:54:49Z",
    "trace_id": "ce5c37f6-57c0-44f6-b265-ccc68602ba00",
    "correlation_id": "a44a64c1-9277-40e3-b855-ee0abbe44ab6"
}
```

Scopes --
[image: Scopes In Azure]
But the same thing works in postman when with authorization using oauth2.0, I'm able to generate the token. Please help with the post request which fetches the bearer token from azure AD.

Comment: Hi @Rahul,What is the auth flow you are using?

Comment: I referred to this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#request-a-token and the api is written as a microsoft workflow in powerapps. where in, while getting token it fails and throws the error i sent in the question.

Comment: You need to pass scope in the authentication URL.can you share us the link of your authentication URL

Comment: URL - https://login.microsoftonline.com/*****-*****-****-****-****/oauth2/v2.0/token

Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type : client_credentials

Comment: scope : api://****/Access.As.User

Comment: If i fill up the fields in postman. I'm able to get the token. But can't figure out how to get the same while using API

Comment: Now I understood what is the issue.You are using client credential flow. It will only accept scope with .default. i.e., your scope must look like `api://{your-appid}/ .default`

Comment: Using .deafult, I'm getting token. But I can't expose the api with scope api://***/.default. The error says in azure portal as-- Failed to update  application property. Error detail: Property  has an invalid value.[B/LVq6XGXCJmjh/jimZAVz]

Comment: Also, the token which i get from .default, When i use it as a bearer token for authenticating my Apis it throws 401, unauthorized.

Comment: Are you using graph or any api?

Comment: I'm using Api which is hosted in azure app service. Its a .net core 3.1 web api application. I registered the app under azure active directory and gave a scope as Access.As.User and generated a client certificate and tried generating token from postman. When i filled up the values, I received a token which i used for my api end point and it works. But, I have to do the same thing what postman does in an api. I have shared a screenshot of the scopes in my question.

Comment: I am asking because the issues `Property has an invalid value.` and `401, unauthorized. ` occurring because you are doing a update request to an api  but you don't have permissions and also the parameters you are trying to update are incorrect.

Comment: Please provide a resolution then. I can't understand why the same works with postman but not while using the api

Comment: Your new edited post gives me the clear reason why you are getting this unauthorized  issue. Let me draft it as an answer which will also help the users with the same issue and reduce the amount of conversation space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Client credential flow* the scope parameter in the request should be, Scope =`api://{your-appid}/ .default` (Suffix) . Please refer [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes#scopes-to-request-for-a-client-credential-flowdaemon-app) that also mentions the same.

According to the screenshot you have shared all permissions assigned are *delegated* permissions.Since, *Client credential flow* only supports *application* permissions and this is the reason you are facing `401, unauthorized` issue.Please Add the application permissions to fix this issue.

Comment: In my api, only the logged in user can only access the api, In postman also, after i click on generate access token, it asks for my user id and password. After entering it correctly, I get a token. So, how do you add a scope as .default in portal

Comment: You need to expose an api with out adding additional scope.Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#:~:text=%20First%2C%20follow%20these%20steps%20to%20create%20an,specify%20the%20scope%27s%20attributes%20in%20the...%20More%20